# Does anyone know how to control the stroke width of a shape using a control layer?

Tags: after-effects, after-effects-expressions

I recently created the attached graphic in Illustrator for a project and am trying to figure out how to create something similar in After Effects perhaps using a control layer.

The idea is that I want the width of the stroke on each of the lines to be linked to the black/white values of the control layer, which would have my letter W on it in this case.

I've achieved similar results in the past linking the scale of a shape layer with the colour value of a control layer but I can't figure out how to repurpose that technique for this job.

Any advice would be very welcome and appreciated!

R

[image: Original vector artwork I am trying to recreate in After Effects in the past]

Comment: Interesting question. I wonder if a similar effect could be achieve using a particle generator like form or particular somehow...

Answer (score 0):

I would use the ol' blur-and-threshold trick:

- make my lines slightly thicker than they need to be,
- precompose my lines and the control layer, and set the opacity of the control layer to say 50%.
- Then back in the original comp I would add Gaussian blur to the precomped layers, followed by the threshold effect.
- Muck around with the values for both effects and the opacity of the control layer until it's good.